# I m trying to user useRef inside the JS class but really but i don't how to do that for example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
class postArticle extends Component {
  //here I m using state to store the Out put from user

  state = {
    Article: {
      id: null,
      type: "Blog",
      title: "Raj",
      body: "reani ak Kahain bas pyar aur pahana",
      author: "Suresh",
    },
  };

  inputHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = e.target.name;
    const input = e.target.value;
    console.log(name);
    switch (name) {
      case "type":
        //Here I want  to use useRef but I don't know how to declare it inside the class

        this.setState({ Article: { type: input } });
        break;
      case "title":
        //Here I want  to use useRef but I don't know how to declare it inside the class

        this.setState({ Article: { title: input } });
        break;
      case "article":
        //Here I want  to use useRef but I don't know how to declare it inside the class

        this.setState({ Article: { body: input } });
        console.log(this.state.Article);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("wrong input");
        break;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <UserPostContainr>
        <UserPostForm>
          <div className="mb-3 text-center fw-1">
            <UserPostLabel name="Type" />
            <UserPostInput
              type="text"
              place="Type of article"
              name="type"
              change={this.inputHandler}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3 text-center fw-1">
            <UserPostLabel name="Title" />
            <UserPostInput
              type="text"
              place="Title of your Article"
              name="title"
              change={this.inputHandler}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3 text-center fw-1">
            <UserPostLabel name="Write your article" />
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              name="article"
              rows="3"
              onChange={this.inputHandler}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.postHandler}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </UserPostForm>
      </UserPostContainr>
    );
  }
}
```

**so please guys help me to solve this problem**

Comment: In class components refs are done via `createRef`, not `useRef`, but what do you plan to use the ref for? I don't see how a ref would be useful with this code.

Comment:  tbh - anyways [see creating ref's in class components](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)

Comment: what should i need to use at place of state ?